# In python, from a column how to check specific word/tag and show their presence in their new related columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am new in python. I have a Column in MS Excel file, in which `four tag` are used which are `LOC , ORG , PER` and `MISC` ,`given data` is **like this:**

```
1 LOC/Thai Buddhist temple;
2 PER/louis;
3 ORG/WikiLeaks;LOC/Southern Ocean;
4 ORG/queen;
5 PER/Sanchez;PER/Eli Wallach;MISC/The Good, The Bad and the Ugly;
6 
7 PER/Thomas Watson;
...................
...................
.............#continue upto 2,000 rows
```

and i want a Result that in the specific row which tag is present or not ,if some tag is present then in their specific (NEW Columns which are shown below) column put `"1"` and if not present any tag then put `"0"` . I want all 4 columns in this excel file which are  LOC/ORG/PER/MISC and will be 2nd ,3rd, 4th and 5th column while `first column is given data`,and  file is contains almost 2815 rows and every row has different tag from these LOC/ORG/PER/MISC .

My goal is to count from the new columns

> total number of LOC, total number of ORG, total number of PER and total number of MISC

The result will be **like this:**

```
             given data              LOC  ORG  PER MISC
1 LOC/Thai Buddhist temple;           1    0    0   0   #here only LOC is present
2 PER/louis;                          0     0    1  0   #here only PER is present
3 ORG/WikiLeaks;LOC/Southern Ocean;   1     1   0   0   #here LOC and ORG is present
4 PER/Eli Wallach;MISC/The Good;      0     0   1   1   #here PER and MISC is present
5    .................................................
6                                     0     0   0   0   #here no tag is present
7 .....................................................
.......................................................
..................................continue up to 2815 rows....
```

I am beginner in Python.so,  I have tried my best to search out its solution code but, I cannot find any program related to my problem that's why I posted here. so, kindly anyone helps me.

Comment: You may try `.sum(axis=0)`.

Comment: do you have pandas installed? are you working on pandas? Have ypu read this data into python?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have successfully read the data from excel and created a dataframe in python using pandas (To read the excel file we have df1 = read_excel("File/path/name.xls" Header = True/False)).

Here is the layout of your dataframe df1

```
Colnum | Tagstring
1      |LOC/Thai Buddhist temple;
2      |PER/louis;
3      |ORG/WikiLeaks;LOC/Southern Ocean;
4      |ORG/queen;
5      |PER/Sanchez;PER/Eli Wallach;MISC/The Good, The Bad and the Ugly;
6      |PER/Thomas Watson;
```

Now, there are couple of ways to search for text in a string.

I will demonstrate find function :

Syntax :   str.find(str, beg=0, end=len(string))

```
str1 = "LOC";
str2 = "PER";
str3 = "ORG";
str4 = "MISC";

df1["LOC"] = (if Tagstring.find(str1) >= 0 then 1 else 0).astype('int')
df1["PER"] = (if Tagstring.find(str2) >= 0 then 1 else 0).astype('int')
df1["ORG"] = (if Tagstring.find(str3) >= 0 then 1 else 0).astype('int')
df1["MISC"] = (if Tagstring.find(str4) >= 0 then 1 else 0).astype('int')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have read your data, `df` then you can do:

```
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame({i:df.Tagstring.str.contains(i).astype(int) for i in 'LOC  ORG  PER MISC'.split()})],axis=1)
Out[716]: 
                                                 Tagstring  LOC  ORG  PER    MISC 
Colnum                                                                      
1                                LOC/Thai Buddhist temple;    1    0    0       0
2                                               PER/louis;    0    0    1       0
3                        ORG/WikiLeaks;LOC/Southern Ocean;    1    1    0       0
4                                               ORG/queen;    0    1    0       0
5        PER/Sanchez;PER/Eli Wallach;MISC/The Good, The...    0    0    1       1
6                                       PER/Thomas Watson;    0    0    1       0
```